# Sequelize.define cannot merge optional object into the Model constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i'm mocking for a simple messaging service bulit with express and sequelize.js and
trying to do with sequelize.define("Model", Desc, Opt) syntax.
However, additional class methods in Opt argument cannot be loaded for Model objects.
Do you have any idea to make these objects had additional method, specified with Opt json? (named **associate** in the sample below)

I used node v10.16.0 and sequelize@5.21.3.

Ref: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-define

My code and corresponding error messages:

```js
  const Messages = sequelize.define("Messages", {
    id: {
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    place: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    },
    message: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        Messages.belongsTo(models.Users);
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(typeof Messages);
  console.log(Messages);
  console.log(typeof Messages.associate);
  console.log(Messages.associate);
```

```
> app1@1.0.0 start /home/neko/PJDir/app1
> node app.js

consign v0.1.6 Initialized in /home/neko/PJDir/app1
+ ./libs/config.js
+ ./db.js
+ ./models/messages.js
+ ./models/users.js
+ ./libs/middlewares.js
+ ./routes/index.js
+ ./routes/message.js
+ ./libs/boot.js
function
Messages
undefined
undefined
/home/neko/PJDir/app1/db.js:34
      db.models[key].associate(db.models);
                     ^

TypeError: db.models[key].associate is not a function
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (/home/neko/PJDir/app1/db.js:34:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.module.exports.app (/home/neko/PJDir/app1/db.js:32:28)
    at Consign.into (/home/neko/PJDir/app1/node_modules/consign/lib/consign.js:240:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/neko/PJDir/app1/app.js:12:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app1@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app1@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
const Messages = sequelize.define('Messages', {
  id: {
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  place: {
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  },
  message: {
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: false
  }
}, {
  tableName: 'messages'
})

Messages.associate = function (models) {
  Messages.belongsTo(models.Users);
  Messages.hasMany(/* other relations */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but here, node says `TypeError: defineCall is not a function` and abort with sequelize internal error (/home/neko/PJDir/api2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:486).

Comment: You're not importing **Uses** model
In my project I've used `sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, fileName))` and then  i'm assigning it to models using 

`Object.keys(models).forEach(modelName => {
    if (models[modelName].associate) {
      models[modelName].associate(models)
    }
  })`


please share you user model details and parent function or parent class methods which are in use

Comment: actually the right function is **belongsTo** instead of **belongTo**

I'm updating my code in above answer

Comment: Sorry I tried in wrong directory in previous comment, but, in the correct PJ directory, node also aborted `TypeError: Messages.belongTo is not a function` : (scope error?)

Comment: Thank you, errors around Messages model are cleared. But i got another probrem `Error: Users.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`. (Both of Users and Messages models were confirmed to be imported). users.js (model) has similar style with messages.js and User has several(many) messages, as you guess.

Comment: Thanks for valuable advices. I'll share that.

Comment: but my main question is "Why does Sequelize.define(model, attr, opt) not work".  so this post will not be closed, sorry

Comment: because you can not define function in third parameter of the define method. 
you can only pass options check this link - you can only pass this options 

https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/#configuration

even I've used third parameter to mention tablename in my code

Comment: OK, understood. I picked code fragments from ISBN 978-1-4842-2441-0 https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781484224410, its codes assign THREE arguments for sequelize.define. Maybe his codes or my eyes  are buggy.

Comment: Author is using **sequelize@3.19.0**. I'm not sure if this is the issue and one more thing to note is that author used **classMethods** object in 3rd argument of the **define** method and then inside classMethods **associate** is defined. 

please check the version as well because current version has hell lot of change

Comment: I see. Also sequelize has had many changes from v3.19 but the version includes vulnerable packages at now. I didn't know whether the classMethod object assignment for **define** method was deprecated and removed from sequelize, or not. Simply I tried to use it and got this probrem, ... and won't try that again for a while. Thanks a lot! I'll make next issue.

Comment: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models (maybe a treasure)

Comment: Yes, i close it.